# How does loop work in decorator (memoization)

Tags: python, decorator, memoization

Memoization is a powerful tool. I try to understand the fundamental mechanism, but it seems not to work in the way how I thought. Could anyone explain how it works in the following code in detail?

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:            
            memo[x] = f(x)
        print(memo)
        return memo[x]

    return helper

@memoize
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

What really confuses me is when the decorator `memoize` comes into work in this example. According to a [tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator), it seems the whole function to be decorated runs in the decorator. Here the function is `fib(n)`. If so, how is the loop in the `fib(n)` handled in decorator `memoize(f)`?

Let's take `fib(4)` as an example to demystify the process:

```
In [1]: fib(4)
{1: 1}
{1: 1, 0: 0}
{1: 1, 0: 0, 2: 1}
{1: 1, 0: 0, 2: 1}
{1: 1, 0: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2}
{1: 1, 0: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2}
{1: 1, 0: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3}
```

Why is the first value printed out in `memoize(f)` is `{1: 1}`? I expect `memoize(f)`to store memo = {4 : f(4)} at the very beginning even though the the value of f(4) was not known yet at that moment. I know I was wrong. Could anyone one explain how we get these output and how the loop in `fib(n)` works in `memoize(f)`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have a chain of 5 "cache misses" before you reach to _any_ print statement.  That's how the recursive call works, it's like a depth first search but the stack *is* the call stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memo` cache doesn't get populated until the function call returns:

`memo[x] = f(x)`

Since the loop is recursive, there are a bunch more calls to `f` before that first `f(4)` finishes returning and populates the cache.  The first one of those calls to actually return is `f(1)`, followed by `f(0)`, etc (as seen in your print statements).

If you were to add another `print` at the start of `helper` (*before* you call `f`) then you'd see the recursive calls as a sandwich, with `f(4)` starting first but finishing last.

Here's how you could modify the print statements to show the recursion depth as well:

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    depth = [0]
    def helper(x):
        print(f"{'  '*depth[0]}Calling f({x})...")
        depth[0] += 1
        if x not in memo:            
            memo[x] = f(x)
        print(f"{'  '*depth[0]}Cached: {memo}")
        depth[0] -= 1
        print(f"{'  '*depth[0]}Finished f({x})!")
        return memo[x]

    return helper

@memoize
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

prints:

```
Calling f(4)...
  Calling f(3)...
    Calling f(2)...
      Calling f(1)...
        Cached: {1: 1}
      Finished f(1)!
      Calling f(0)...
        Cached: {1: 1, 0: 0}
      Finished f(0)!
      Cached: {1: 1, 0: 0, 2: 1}
    Finished f(2)!
    Calling f(1)...
      Cached: {1: 1, 0: 0, 2: 1}
    Finished f(1)!
    Cached: {1: 1, 0: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2}
  Finished f(3)!
  Calling f(2)...
    Cached: {1: 1, 0: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2}
  Finished f(2)!
  Cached: {1: 1, 0: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3}
Finished f(4)!
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the easiest way to understand the decorators (without parameter) is to see the following equivalence

```
@memoize
def f():
    ...

# is the same as


def f():
   ...
f = memoize(f)
```

Thus the code

```
@memoize
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

is equivalent to

```
def not_decorated_fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def fib(x):
    if x not in memo:            
        memo[x] = not_decorated_fib(x)
    print(memo)
    return memo[x]
```

Which means you will have the following call stack:

- Stack level 0: `fib(4)` calls `not_decorated_fib(4)` since `memo` is
  empty
- Stack level 1: `not_decorated_fib(4)` calls  `fib(3)` (`+ fib(2)` will only be called after `fib(3)` has been resolved )
- Stack level 2: `fib(3)` calls  not_decorated_fib(3) since `memo` is
  still empty
- Stack level 3: `not_decorated_fib(3)` calls `fib(2)`
- Stack level 4: `fib(2)` calls  `not_decorated_fib(2)` since `memo` is
  still empty
- Stack level 5: `not_decorated_fib(2)` calls `fib(1)`
- Stack level 6: fib(1) calls  not_decorated_fib(1) since `memo` is
  still empty
- Stack level 7: `not_decorated_fib(1)` returns 1 (end condition)
- Stack level 6: `fib(1)`: `memo[1]` is set since the `not_decorated_fib(1)`, we get the first print `{1:1}` and `fib(1)` returns 1
- Stack level 5: `not_decorated_fib(2)` calls `fib(0)` (evaluation of the second part of `fib(1) + fib(0)`)
- Stack level 6: `fib(0)` calls  `not_decorated_fib(0)`
- Stack level 7: `not_decorated_fib(0)` returns 0 (end condition)
- Stack level 6: `fib(0)`: `memo[0]` is set since the `not_decorated_fib(0)`, we get the second print `{1:1, 0:0}` and `fib(0)` returns 0

and it similar fashion the rest of the function is executed